# What are those black fibers in my mango?

Tags: mango

I was cutting up a mango, when I noticed some black threads inside.

What are those?

They are quite tough, brown-black, about an inch long (2.5 cm):

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an indication that the fruit has started to rot.

> When dark spots start appearing on the side of a mango, it's starting to rot. A mango can rot from the pit, the skin, or from the non-stem end. Any black fibers also indicate that the fruit has started to rot, and at that point, you need to toss it into the trash.
>
> *From [Student's Vegetarian Cookbook For Dummies, page 301](http://books.google.com/books?id=gpv1zB1mpg8C&pg=PT301)*

Yes, the above is probably being overcautious in stating “*any* black fibers? → trash! It's from a “Dummies” book after all. I couldn't really find another good reference, but I'm sure you can make the distinction between a piece of fruit that has a small brown spot and one that's black and shriveled.

Still, the color of the fibers is a result of the late ripening/rotting process of the mango, rather than a result of an earlier stage in its growth, but having eaten this mango with the one, tiny black fiber shown in her picture, I don't really expect to read Mien's obituary on this site tomorrow.

Comment: I don't think it's *rotten* at that point. Overripe, sure. But, though I don't have a source off the top of my head, anecdotally, I've eaten *tons* of overripe mangos containing a few black fibers, and they tasted great and caused me no problems.

Comment: Overripe mangoes are good for making mango ice-cream (the rotten sections need to be thrown off though).

Comment: It appears that Mien survived at least 5 years after eating this mango.

Answer (score 8):

Black streaks in mango.  Please read the following articles from www.abc.net.au:

- [Mango industry baffled by mystery disorder](http://www.abc.net.au/site-archive/rural/news/content/201302/s3683453.htm)
- [Mystery mango disease not so mysterious](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2013-12-17/resin-canal-cure/5161094)

These articles identify the presence of well delineated black veins in otherwise good, fresh mango as a "disease" of the fruit. It turns out that this is caused by the mango trees lacking sufficient fertilizer.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. This time I added two sentences for you, but you may expand it too, to make your answer better.

Comment: That's actually very good information, +1. Links go bad and not everyone likes to click them. To make this a stellar answer, take rumtscho's advice!

Comment: Also sidesteps the question whether fruit so affected are inedible and/or harmful to eat...

Comment: Recent evidence seems to indicate this is caused by [bacteria infecting the fruit](https://www.abc.net.au/news/rural/2019-03-19/resin-canal-discolouration-breakthrough-for-mango-industry/10912520)

Answer (score 6):

I believe some mangos do that in early stages of over-ripening (similar to how an avocado does that). I usually cut around them and keep eating.

Answer (score 2):

It's not mango rot its actually a disease called Resin Canal which causes black fibers to appear in mangoes, there is no idea what causes the problem

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice and thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer! Here is some help on [how to write a good answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Can you cite the source of your information?

Answer (score 1):

Mango industry discovers highly infectious bacteria as cause of ugly veins of resin canal discolouration

https://www.abc.net.au/news/rural/2019-03-19/resin-canal-discolouration-breakthrough-for-mango-industry/10912520

Comment: I also would like to know why the best answer on here has the least points, in fact one minus (see below the answer of Raimond!)

Answer (score 1):

Just to keep this thread accurate and current, the black fibers/veins in the picture are known as Resin Canal Disease, or RCD. Although unappealing, they are safe to eat, as described in this article: https://www.abc.net.au/news/rural/2019-03-19/resin-canal-discolouration-breakthrough-for-mango-industry/10912520